# Design-time support of Image?

Tags: wpf, design-time

I just wonder why VS provides me with a small window for editing `Image.Source` property.

I'm writting a similiar WPF element with Source property as well. I want to make use of the small window to input image path.

I've read some articles regarding WPF design-time support.

Reflector tells me the `Image` element is in *PresentationFramework.dll* and according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee849818.aspx, the design-time metadate should be found in *PresentationFramework.VisualStudio.Design.dll*.

I searched in the assembly for keyword *Image*, but didn't anything related to the Image element.

Can anybody help me find out where the small window is?